# Storyboard segue is slow only the first time it is pressed

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have a UINavigationController, and the Root View Controller contains a UITableView. In the storyboard, I attach a segue from the UITableViewCells to another UIViewController.

When I'm on the Root View Controller and I tap a UITableViewCell it takes between 1 and 4 seconds to perform the segue to the other UIViewController. However, because this is all in a UINavigationController, I could go back to the Root View Controller. When I go back and try the segue again (from any cell), it happens instantly. It is only slow the first time I do the segue. Why is this?

I'd post code, but this is all extremely vanilla stuff and it is slow even when my `viewDidLoad` method in the destination View Controller is empty.

Comment: Does the same happen in real device too?

Comment: I've only tested it on real devices.

Comment: Does your UIViewController contains complex layout constraints?

Comment: None. Even then, if it did, why wouldn't it take a few seconds to load every time I segue to that UIViewController?